# ARM cortex-M3 uint_fast32_t vs uint32_t

Tags: c, types, sizeof, cortex-m, primitive-types

I am developing a program for an STM32Fx cortex-M3 series processor. In stdint.h the following are defined:

```
typedef unsigned int uint_fast32_t;
typedef uint32_t  uint_least32_t;
typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
```

As I understand it.

```
[u]int_fast[n]_t will give you the fastest data type of at least n bits.
[u]int_least[n]_t will give you the smallest data type of at least n bits.
[u]int[n]_t will give you the data type of exactly n bits.
```

Also as far as i know sizeof(unsigned int) <= sizeof(unsigned long) and UINT_MAX <= ULONG_MAX - always.

Thus I would expect uint_fast32_t to be a data type with a size equal to or greater than the size of uint32_t.

In the case of the cortex-M3 sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(unsigned long) == 4. So the above definitions are 'correct' in terms of size.

But why are they not defined in a way that is consistent with the names and logical sizes of the underlying data types i.e.

```
typedef unsigned long uint_fast32_t;
typedef unsigned int  uint_least32_t;
typedef uint_fast32_t uint32_t;
```

Can someone please clarify the selection of the underlying types?

Given that 'long' and 'int' are the same size, why not use the same data type for all three definitions?

```
typedef unsigned int uint_fast32_t;
typedef unsigned int uint_least32_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
```

Answer (score 3):

The case is, it is only guaranteed that

```
sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)
```

and it is not guaranteed that it is actually any longer. On a lot of systems, int is usually as big as long.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough in the original post, so I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11518212/827263).

Basically, it doesn't matter which type is used.  Given that `int` and `long` are the same size and have the same representation and other characteristics, the implementer can choose either type for `int32_t`, `int_fast32_t`, and `int_least32_t`, and likewise for the corresponding unsigned versions.

(It's possible that the particular choices could be influenced by a perceived need to use the same header for implementations with different sizes for `int` and `long`, but I don't see how the particular definitions you quoted would achieve that.)

As long as the types are the right size and meet all the other requirements imposed by the standard, and as long as you don't write code that depends on, for example, `int32_t` being compatible with `int`, or with `long`, it doesn't matter.

The particular choices made were likely an arbitrary whim of the implementer -- which is perfectly acceptable.  Or perhaps that header file was modified by two or more developers who had different ideas about which type is best.

Comment: From what I understand, an operation involving a signed `long` and an unsigned `int` will be coerce the unsigned value to signed, even if both variables are the same size.  If both `int` and `long` are 32 bits, and 32-bit operations are often enough faster than 16-bit operations to justify making `uint_fast16_t` also be 32 bits, then it would probably be good to use `long` for the "32"-bit types but `int` for the "fast 16" bit type, so that an operation between an `int32_t` and a `uint_fast16_t` would be performed as signed.

Comment: Actually an operation involving `signed long` and `unsigned int`, if both are the same size (with the usual ranges) will convert both operands to `unsigned long`, because `signed long` cannot represent all values of type `unsigned int`. The rules are in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.1.8p1, at the end of the paragraph; this case falls through to the 5th and final sub-paragraph.

Comment: I'd thought that the standard was changed to introduce the concept of "rank", where "long" was considered to have a higher rank than "int", regardless of size, though I sometimes lose track of which changes apply to C or C++.  Personally, I wish the standards bodies could deprecate some C baggage and facilitate migration toward use of new types which would generally behave like old ones when appropriate, but which unlike old ones would squawk at inappropriate usage.  C allows unsigned types to behave as abstract algebraic rings (e.g. 8-bit unsigned values behave like members of Z256)...

Comment: @supercat: The concept of *integer conversion rank* was introduced by C99 -- but the rules I cited (the "usual arithmetic conversions") uses ranges, not ranks, when dealing with signed vs. unsigned types. For signed vs. signed or unsigned vs. unsigned, a type of higher rank always includes all the values of a type with lower rank. For signed vs. unsigned, that's not necessarily the case. I think C90 didn't bother defining "rank" because it had fewer types to deal with. (Hmm, I forgot to tag you on my previous comment; how did you see it so quickly? Did it show up in your inbox?)

Comment: According to https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules a `long` has greater rank than `int`, and unsigned types have the same rank as like-sized signed types.  That would imply that `signed long` would have higher rank than `unsigned int`, and so operands would be converted to the signed type.  Care to chat?

Comment: @supercat: Rank is not the only consideration. The rules at the end of 6.3.1.8p1 also take ranges into account. Read that, and if you still think there's a problem I'll be glad to chat.

Comment: My understanding is that the old rules were based solely upon representable range, but that the rules were since changed because it was judged unlikely that code which was e.g. comparing an unsigned char to a signed long would be intending for the conversion to be performed as unsigned, regardless of the sizes of the operands.  It's too bad many languages seem to have followed C's example of using the same types for natural numbers and algebraic rings, and use some rules which make sense for one, some which make sense for the other, and some which make sense for neither.

Comment: For any integer n of any size, and any algebraic ring, there will exactly one ring element which can be reached by adding the ring's multiplicative identity to zero n times, or subtracting it from zero -n times.  Thus, adding an integer *of any size* to a member of an algebraic ring (Z65536) should yield a member of that same algebraic ring.  On the other hand, an operation between a signed integer type and a natural number type should coerce the values to an integer type that can hold all values of both (note that for the largest integer type, there would be a corresponding ring type...

Comment: ...but not a corresponding natural number type).  If a language allowed implicit conversions from numbers to rings, but required explicit conversions back to numbers, I would expect there would be relatively few surprises with code that compiles, and when code doesn't compile it would usually be obvious what would need to be done to fix it.  The biggest difficulty I would see if the standards committee tried to add new types would be figuring out what to do with things like `size_t` which should represent a number but, being defined unsigned, has historically been an algebraic ring.

Comment: I reread the rules and I see where I'd misinterpreted them, though such rereading leaves me curious as to the purpose of rank.  If X and Y are integral types of the same size, in what plausible implementations would rank be important?  I'd thought they'd changed things so that e.g. code which was read an octet into an unsigned char and tried to do something like `if (someInt > otherInt+newByte)` would behave consistently even on implementations where `unsigned char` was the same size as `int`.  No matter what rule applies, surprising behavior is going to arise in one of two cases:...

Comment: ...either when the "smaller" unsigned value holds a value which can't fit in the "larger" signed type, or when a "larger" signed type gets converted to unsigned.  I'd thought that the standards committee had regarded the former situation as less problematic (since it would only causes problems if unsigned type is used to hold values which exceed the maximum for its corresponding signed type, while the latter can cause trouble with even small values e.g. `(-1ll < (unsigned char)0)`.  Personally, with rules as they are I'd be surprised if more than a tiny fraction of code is really portable.