# C99′s Fixed-Width Integer Types

Tags: c, int, long-integer, c99, fixed-width

Failing to get a detailed answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381764/arm-cortex-m3-uint-fast32-t-vs-uint32-t). I thought I would tackle it from a different angle.

Would someone be able to explain what selection criteria are used for determining the underlying types for C99's fixed-width integer types:

```
[u]int_fast[n]_t
[u]int_least[n]_t
[u]int[n]_t
```

For a given processor, if 'long' and 'int' are the same size (sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)) then why would 'long' be used over 'int' or vice versa.

Comment: One reason this didn't get any attention in Stack Overflow is that you completely omitted the C tag (or the c99 tag, though the C tag would be better).  The tags present are not the ones that people will follow; they won't see such questions in their customized view of SO.  As a newcomer, you might not be aware of the nuances, but I follow about 50 tags (including C and C99), and there's a very high chance I never saw this until you mentioned it on comp.lang.c — though there is an outside chance I looked and decided not to answer.  I've retagged, omitting the least useful two tags.

Answer (score 5):

The whim of the author of `<stdint.h>`.

Given that `int` and `long` are the same size (and assuming they have the same representation and other characteristics), it shouldn't matter at all which of them is used to define `[u]int_{,_fast,_least}32_t`, as long as the type or types satisfy the requirements of the standard.

Well, that's not *quite* true; it can make a difference in some cases.  `int` and `long`, even if they're the same size, are still distinct and incompatible types.  For example, given that `int32_t` is `typedef`ed either as `int` or as `long`, the following program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
int main(void) {
    int32_t *p32 = NULL;
    int  *ip = p32;
    long *lp = p32;
    return  0;
}
```

violates a constraint and requires a diagnostic *either* on the declaration of `ip` *or* on the declaration of `lp`, depending on how `int32_t` is defined.  But you should avoid writing such code anyway.